# Gallery Images loading properly fast in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm building a website using Bootstrap and LightSlider.
It contains LightSlider-gallerys being filled by js.

I'm currently coding with Brackets and its Chrome live-preview and it's working fine.
Watching the page load in the network monitor of Chrome I can see that it's successfully loading all images after loading the html.

When i'm clicking through the gallery, even at 5 slides per second, chrome and IE are doing fine. Firefox instead is swiping the old image away, then nothing happens, and the next slide pops out in the center instead of sliding in. Watching the network monitor in Firefox it also says that the images are loading fine... I have no clue why that's happening.

Here are my Code Snippets, wasn't able to get them working in JSFiddle because of external library:

```js
var i = 1;
    for (i; i <= image_count; i++) {
        $('<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></li>').appendTo('#lightSlider');
    }
    var slider = $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
        gallery: false,
        item: 1,
        loop: false,
        slideMargin: 0,

        autoWidth: false,
        slideMove: 1, // slidemove will be 1 if loop is true
        slideMargin: 10,

        speed: 400, //ms
        auto: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        slideEndAnimation: true,
        pause: 4000,

        addClass: 'style_slider',
        mode: "slide",
        useCSS: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',//
        easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',////

        keyPress: true,
        pager: false,
        currentPagerPosition: 'middle',

        enableTouch:true,
        enableDrag:true,
        freeMove:true,
        swipeThreshold: 40,

        responsive : [
        ]

    });
    $('#goToPrevSlide').click(function(){
        slider.goToPrevSlide(); 
    });
    $('#goToNextSlide').click(function(){
        slider.goToNextSlide(); 
    });
```

```html
< div class = "col-lg-12"
id = "col_lightSlider" >
  <!-- Begin LightSlider -->
  <
  ul id = "lightSlider" >
  <!-- Content is filled here -->
  <
  /ul>
  <!-- End LightSlider -->
  <
  a id = "goToPrevSlide"
class = "left carousel-control ctrl_left"
role = "button" >
  <
  span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
aria - hidden = "true" > < /span> <
  span class = "sr-only" > Previous < /span> <
  /a> <
  a id = "goToNextSlide"
class = "right carousel-control ctrl_right"
role = "button" >
  <
  span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
aria - hidden = "true" > < /span> <
  span class = "sr-only" > Next < /span> <
  /a>  <
  /div>
  <!-- Script is called here like this fill_data("path", imagecount)-->
  <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  fill_data("MobileIron_ersteinrichtung", 34); <
/script>
```

Comment: Update: I've redone the whole stuff by copy-pasting all 34 <li><img....></li> elements straight into the HTML code and it's still not working (in firefox).